# Modal viewController dismiss button problem

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller

I'm creating a simple modal ViewController. I'm creating a nib with a button and on that button press calling a method to display modal viewController in which I'm creating the viewController and a button inside it like this.

```
UIViewController *modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
modalViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
modalViewController.;

UIButton *btnDismissViewController = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnDismissViewController.frame = CGRectMake(60, 160, 150, 50);
[btnDismissViewController setTitle:@"DISMISS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnDismissViewController addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissViewCOntroller) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

btnDismissViewController.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[modalViewController.view addSubview:btnDismissViewController];

[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

This view is appearing properly but after pressing the button on modalViewController, the  target method for dismissing the modalViewController isn't called. I'm definitely missing something obvious but not getting what. Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please show us the definition of the `dismissViewCOntroller` method. The way you defined the selector, it should look like this, with two capital letters and all: `- (void)dismissViewCOntroller` (no sender argument).

Comment: Also, are you sure you didn't mean to write `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`?

Comment: Thanx, Ole, IWasRobbed and Macatomy... Yes, there was a typo.. I should have written "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" which accidently was written as UIControlEventTouchUpOutside..

Comment: this Question is answered here 

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557425/modal-view-controller-wont-dismiss-itself

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ole's comment... additionally, make sure you are dismissing it within your `dismissViewCOntroller` method similar to this:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a typo in your code, `dismissViewCOntroller` seems like it should be `dismissViewController`, but maybe that was intentional, and the control state should be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.