# DismissModalViewController stuck the app in lower version than iOS 5.0

Tags: ios4, ios5, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

Let´s see, I am developing an app which uses some ModalViewCotrollers. 
When I show any of these modals, everything is going OK, I can work with it and interact with his content. The problem comes when I try to do:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This problem, only happens in lower version than iOS 5.0

The modals are called from my DetailViewController (in Master-Detail app).

Any suggestion??

Thanks everybody in advanced!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried if you are dismissing from the correct view controller??
Like this:

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Anyway, I found a couple of good links which could be helpful for you:

[Modal view controller won't dismiss itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557425/modal-view-controller-wont-dismiss-itself)

[dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: (and dismissViewControllerAnimated) crashing in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821617/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-and-dismissviewcontrolleranimated-crashing)

Comment: i haven´t found the solution to fix this problem, but, at the moment, i show Modal into the splitViewController.

[appDelegate.splitViewController presentModalViewController:articuloWeb animated:YES];

So, the modal will disappear correctly.

Thanks for everybody anyway!!